# Why does AWS Lambda CFN S3-response returns 403 upon Delete event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm using [serverless](https://serverless.com/) to deploy an application where I use a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to migrate a RDS database.

Everything works while I deploy, but when I delete the stack the Custom Resource timeouts after an hour with the message "Custom Resource failed to stabilize in expected time.". The request to the pre-signed AWS S3 URL returns `403` with the error code `AccessDenied`.

My first sent, successfull, response body to the pre-signed URL (upon Create):

```
{
    "Status": "SUCCESS",
    "RequestId": "bd487606-8017-49f2-99af-b29b2bbad40b",
    "LogicalResourceId": "SheltersDBMigrationTrigger",
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:848139458219:stack/update-shelters-dev/c08a80e0-2e4e-11e9-87a6-124d1eab42ba",
    "PhysicalResourceId": "DB_MIGRATION"
}
```

My second sent, failing, response body to the pre-signed URL (upon Delete):

```
{
    "Status": "SUCCESS",
    "RequestId": "2d166d36-7c0c-4848-9eb5-aedaf5e9172c",
    "LogicalResourceId": "SheltersDBMigrationTrigger",
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:848139458219:stack/update-shelters-dev/c08a80e0-2e4e-11e9-87a6-124d1eab42ba",
    "PhysicalResourceId": "DB_MIGRATION"
}
```

**lambda.go:**

```
func handler(ctx context.Context, event cfn.Event) (rid string, data map[string]interface{}, err error) {
  rid = "DB_MIGRATION"

  if event.RequestType != cfn.RequestCreate {
    return
  }

  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@(%s)/", os.Getenv("DB_MASTER_USER"), os.Getenv("DB_MASTER_PASSWORD"), os.Getenv("DB_ADDRESS")))
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer db.Close()

  defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
      err = fmt.Errorf("handler: Failed to migrate DB: %v", r)
    }
  }()

  MigrateDb(db)

  return
}

func main() {
  lambda.Start(cfn.LambdaWrap(handler))
}
```

**serverless config for Lambda CFN**:

```
functions:
  dbMigration:
    handler: lambda-bin/migrate-db
    environment:
      DB_MASTER_USER: ${env:DB_MASTER_USER}
      DB_MASTER_PASSWORD: ${env:DB_MASTER_PASSWORD}
      DB_ADDRESS:
        "Fn::GetAtt": [ SheltersDB, Endpoint.Address ]
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - Ref: SheltersVPCSecurityGroup
      subnetIds:
        - Ref: SheltersSubnet1
        - Ref: SheltersSubnet2

...

Resources:
    SheltersDBMigrationTrigger:
      Type: Custom::DBMigration
      DependsOn:
        - SheltersDB
      Properties:
        ServiceToken: !GetAtt
          - DbMigrationLambdaFunction
          - Arn
    SheltersSubnet1:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, {Fn::GetAZs: ""} ]
        CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
        VpcId: !Ref SheltersVPC
    SheltersSubnet2:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, {Fn::GetAZs: ""} ]
        CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
        VpcId: !Ref SheltersVPC
    SheltersVPCSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: "Security group for DB connections"
        VpcId: !Ref SheltersVPC
    SheltersVPCSecurityGroupIngress:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
      Properties:
        GroupId: !Ref SheltersVPCSecurityGroup
        IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: "3306"
        ToPort: "3306"
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref SheltersVPCSecurityGroup
    SheltersVPC:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
    SheltersRouteTable:
      Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref SheltersVPC
    SheltersSubnet1Association:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        SubnetId: !Ref SheltersSubnet1
        RouteTableId: !Ref SheltersRouteTable
    SheltersSubnet2Association:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        SubnetId: !Ref SheltersSubnet2
        RouteTableId: !Ref SheltersRouteTable
    SheltersVPCS3Endpoint:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref SheltersVPC
        PolicyDocument: "{\"Version\":\"2008-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"*\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}"
        RouteTableIds:
          - !Ref SheltersRouteTable
        ServiceName: !Join ['', ['com.amazonaws.', !Ref 'AWS::Region', '.s3']]
```

[Here's a gist with my full source files and log.](https://gist.github.com/kontrollanten/16b991ce664a24413fddec9150587056)

**Update with identified problem**

It seems that my VPCEndpoint to S3, `SheltersVPCS3Endpoint`, is getting deleted before `dBMigration` and that's why I receive 403.

With pure Cloudformation I guess this could've been solved easy by putting a `DependsOn` onto `dbMigration`, but with serverless it seems that's not possible.

Comment: From what I can understand from your source code, you are not returning a success  message when you receive the "DELETE" RequestType. You need to explicitly send a success message when you encounter that otherwise, your CF stack would be stuck.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/tree/master/cfn which wraps the function and handles the response. In the log you can see that the response is sent and also the body I get back.

Comment: Aah, my bad. Although custom resource getting stuck for an hour with failing to stabilize refers to that issue. In that case, check the IAM role associated with the lambda function which is triggered by the custom resource. As i have never used serverless framework and have used SAM, thus it was a but difficult to navigate through. Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh. IAM role may worth investigating further. Do you know which roles that's required to perform this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long investigation together with AWS support we found out that `SheltersVPCS3Endpoint` was deleted before `dbMigration` was deleted, and therefore the Lambda fn couldn't get any contact with the S3 bucket which triggered a timeout.

Since it's not possible to add any `DependsOn` to functions in Serverless, I had to migrate from Serverless to Cloudformation. When I added the following, it seems to be solved.

```
  DbMigrationLambdaFunction:
     DependsOn:
       - SheltersVPCS3Endpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your lambda function the correct permission. 
if you add

```
provider:
  name: aws
  iamRoleStatements:
    $ref: ./iamRoleStatements.json
```

to your serverless config

and then construct your iamRoleStatements.json to give your function permission for S3 buckets placed in the same directory as your serverless config

```
[
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
  }
]
```

this does give all your resources the right to do every thing they want to your s3 bucket

If you want to learn more about working with IAM i serverless functions have a look at
https://serverless.com/blog/abcs-of-iam-permissions/

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't give me permissions that's not mine? The Lambda fn gets a request with a pre signed URL to a CloudFormation owned bucket. It also doesn't explain why it works when Lambda fn receives a Create req, but not a Delete req?